# User Interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 compatibility with application .NET MVC4

Tags: 2011, experience-manager, siteedit

We are using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 to build an application .NET MVC 4. Each page that is published corresponds to a view. It was rejected for technical reasons to use DD4T. Could we still use the User Interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 (aka. UI 2012 or next version of SiteEdit or previous release of Experience Manager aka. XPM) in the system we have?

Comment: your question in not clear, please add more details

Comment: The answer is "yes," but it wouldn't be anything like as straightforward as if you were using DD4T. If you want more specific answers than that, you need to narrow your question down.

Comment: It is rather interesting you mention DD4T was rejected for technical reasons, but you are still requiring something similar to it (.NET MVC with Inline Editing features), so it sounds like you are going to rebuild DD4T. Please note that DD4T is an open source project, and you can just modify whatever is in there that was the cause for the rejection. That would at least save you a lot of time trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: And if DD4T was rejected because it's not supported by SDL, your custom solution is ALSO not going to be supported...

Answer (score 2):

User Interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 (also known as UI 2012) is working on top of your website, so whether you are using an MVC web application, ASP.NET webforms or plain old static HTML pages doesn't really matter.

All you need to make sure is that the correct markup is written out for each Page, Component Presentation and Field you want inline editable.

Depending on how you publish the content to your .NET MVC 4 application, you might still be able to use the Enable (Inline) Editing Template Building Blocks from SDL Tridion to generate this markup, or you might need to generate it yourself as is done [in DD4T](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/branches/web-assembly/dotnet/DD4T.Mvc/SiteEdit/SiteEditService.cs).